# A question about droplets formation

Tags: fluid-dynamics

[image]

This picture shows a fuel ejector of a diesel engine that propels ships.

When the fuel line pressure exceeds 380 bars, the tension of the spring is overcomed and fuel is ejected into the combustion space.

It is common knowledge among engineers and i have read it on manuals that tension of the spring could be adjusted to lift in higher pressures but above this pressure the jet will not penetrate further; instead it will break into smaller droplets.

My question is; Why after a critical value, the surplus energy/pressure we give to a flow does not translate to kinetic energy increase but creates smaller droplets, in other words surfaces?

The flow is sonic, if that is of any help and the speed of the flow is about 500m/sec

Comment: I couldn't understand what is your question exactly (because of my poor English), but I think your question's answer connect to mach number of flow.

Comment: @lucas. My english is also poor. Yes,you are correct the flow is sonic. Waves propagate in the fuel line at the speed of sound

Comment: A detailed explanation would be very technical.  In brief, atomization occurs because of instability of the liquid-air interface : Plateau-Rayleigh Instability. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau%E2%80%93Rayleigh_instability  http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/6/jresv6n3p369_A2b.pdf

Comment: @sammygerbil. Maybe you want to write kelvin-helmholtz instability. But what i don't understand is why an increase in pressure just makes the droplets smaller instead of making them travel faster/further. Why there is no increase in kinetic energy/momentum. thank you for the link

Comment: Maybe KH.  But PR instability describes break-up into droplets, I don't think KH covers that.  Possibly I don't understand enough about the details of fuel injection to appreciate your difficulty.  It seems intuitive to me that forcing a liquid through a nozzle results in atomization above a critical pressure.  Droplets are decelerated much quicker than jets by viscous drag.  Wasn't the paper by Castleman any help to you?

Comment: @sammygerbil sorry, i downloaded but haven't read it yet, i was busy. The pressure of surrounding air is nearly 80 bars and temperature around 500 degrees celsius  so air viscosity is crucial.Droplets are created anyway. But what is the reason that above one limit they don't penetrate further but become more and smaller. Maybe because just they become smaller( less mass, less momentum)

Comment: Yes, I see what you are asking now.  You accept that atomization takes place but want to know why, above a critical pressure, the jet does not penetrate any further before it has completely atomized.  I agree : at higher pressure/speed I would expect the jet to go further.  But I presume you know from experience that it doesn't.  I don't have any explanation for this phenomenon.  On p 376 Castleman notes that up to 100-120 m/s droplet size decreases, but above this limit atomization becomes virtually instantaneous because droplets cannot get any smaller.